# What is the port and part in component diagram in UML

Tags: uml

What does a port and part represent in a component diagram in UML?

Comment: See https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html

Answer (score 1):

A port is a means of gathering a set of interfaces a component might offer. It's analogous to a plug containing data and power cables. On an abstract level you can also hide the interfaces and connect ports directly with an association.

A part is - what the name says - a part of a component. It's used to e.g. group collaborating classes inside a component.

You can read more on pp. 181 chapter Structured Classifiers of UM 2.5